# Creating a four points curve with Geometry Nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, bezier-curves

I need to create a bezier curve with four points using Geometry Nodes.

I found the GN 'Quadratic Bezier' but it only works with 3 points.

The curve I need is like this:

[image: curve with four points]

The second point is calculated from the first, and the third from the fourth.

Any idea ?

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have no idea what you mean with "quadratic bezier works only with 3 points", but with this node setup:

[image]

1. you will learn, that the numbers of points of quadratic bezier depends on resolution
2. you can set each point as you like via index + set position node

Hint: if you change resolution to 3 you will get 4 points as you wanted.

Comment: What a fool!
I saw the start point, mid point and end point in the 'Quadratic Bezier' GN and assumed it only worked for three points. Thanks Chris !